# How do I use WindowManager to overlay an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, popup, android-windowmanager

How can I have an activty overlay like the one used in Facebook Messenger using the `WindowManager`?

> This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

> This is what I have so far

[image: this is what I have so far.]

first widnow manger thats who have chatheads bubble

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
```

This is the code I have for my activity dialog

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();

    params.alpha = 1.0f;    // lower than one makes it more transparent
    params.dimAmount = 0f;  // set it higher if you want to dim behind the window
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;

    params.x = 0;
    params.y = (int) (height - dpToPx(this,40));

    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

This is the activity in my manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.popup"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
        tools:ignore="ExportedActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Here is the `@style/Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup` style in style file I made:

```
 <style name="Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >  
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this it has worked for me.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` view is shown on top of all other applications and activities. Therefore, you can't make any activity appears on top of that view.

To achieve what you want you have to add your chat view to window manager the same way you added the chat bubbles instead of using an activity.

Example:-

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams dialogParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View activityView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, null);
windowManager.addView(activityView, dialogParams);
```

Another solution:-

You can just remove the system alert view temporally when you show your chat activity and make that chat bubbles part of the activity's layout to make it looks like the first image above.

Then you can add the system alert view later when you need to use it (you can attach that to some events such as activity's onPause or when the user click something).